# TableModelEvent.getcolumn() returns -1

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I intent to use a `TableModelListener` to react on user entries of a `JTable`. I would like to know the column of the edited cell. Unfortunately, the method `getColumn()` returns `-1` instead of the edited column number. Any idea why?

```
public class TableEventListener implements TableModelListener {

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

        if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE ) {
            System.out.println(e.getColumn());  //prints -1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) when asking a question. Without seeing the context of how the code is used it is hard to guess what you are doing wrong. Check out this simple SSCCE that works fine using a TableModelListener: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540661/tablemodellistener-and-multiple-column-validation/3541876#3541876

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [`TableModelEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelEvent.html) API for [`getColumn()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelEvent.html#getColumn--), "If the return value is `ALL_COLUMNS`; it means every column in the specified rows changed." Note that [`ALL_COLUMNS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS) has the value -1.