# (Java) Jtable Operations and Exceptions

Tags: java, swing, exception, jtable

I just got this `Jtable` on `Netbeans` . First I want it to auto-calculate some grades, as you can see it has 3 columns (1st, 2nd and 3rd evaluation). I have to type between 0 and 100, in each row.

In the end, get the total and average. This can be displayed in a `Jlabel`, or a `textfield`. But, it has to be displayed real-time (as I'm typing the values).

Also, I can't type data on all the cells, just one for each row. How do I do this?
I know I can change the columns to accept only `Integer` values, but for everything else, I have no idea how to proceed.

[image]

Comment: Thnaks for the edit suggestion. Forgot to mention I'm doing this on NetBeans IDE 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the end, get the total and average. This can be displayed in a Jlabel, or a textfield. But, it has to be displayed real-time (as I'm typing the values).

Well, you would want to update "after" the user has finished editing a cell and saves the value to the table.

So you can use a `TableModelListener`. You add the `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel`. Then when the data is saved an event will be generated and you can recalculate the values and update the label.

Check out the following for a simple example to get your started: [TableModelListener and multiple column validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540661/tablemodellistener-and-multiple-column-validation/3541876#3541876). Your logic in the listener will change based on your exact requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by attaching a defaultTableModel to your JTable. After attaching TableModel to your JTable. You can use command JTable.addRow(Object[]) to add rows to table.

Comment: is this posible on netbeans?