# How to multiply cells in a jtable without any textfield

Tags: java, swing

I have a table with 7 columns and also some rows, I want to multiply cells in the table.
 Say when someone enters a value In (row 0, column 0) and (row 0, column 3) the final answer will automatically appear in (row 0, column 6)

This is my code when some clicks on a cell.
It isn't working

```
Double a=Double.parseDouble ((String) jTable.getValueAt (0,0);
Double b=Double.parseDouble ((String) jTable.getValueAt (0,3);
Double c=a*b;
jTable.setValueAt(c,0,6);
```

Comment: The underlying model inherited from AbstractTableModel have to fire events when model is updated. Please post your custom model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if your columns contain numbers then you should store the `Double` value in the model, not a String.

So you need to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of your `TableModel` to tell the table the type of data stored in the column so the table can use the appropriate renderer/editor.

Some thing like:

```
@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int column)
{
    switch (column)
    {
        case 0: return Double.class;
        case 3: return Double.class;
        case 6: return Double.class;
        default: return Object.class;
    }
}
```

You would also override the `isCellEditable(...)` method to prevent data in column 6 from being edited, since its value will always be the result of values found in columns 0 and 3.

> when someone enters a value

Whenever data is changed in the table the TableModel is updated.

So one approach is to override the `setValueAt(...)` method of your TableModel to recalculate the value for column 6.

The basic logic would be:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column)
{
    super.setValueAt(value, row, column);

    if (column == 0 || or column == 3)
    {
        double column0 = getValueAt(row, 0);
        double column3 = getValueAt(row, 3);
        double result = column0 * column3;
        setValueAt(result, row, 6);
    }
}
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.

Comment: I get it...Am using NetBeans and don't know how to get this done..Am a beginner...and also am using mouseClicked event...Thanks for this though

Comment: @PrinceAsamoah, Which is why I always suggest you don't use an IDE to generated code for you. Don't be restricted by your knowledge of the IDE. Just use the IDE the help compile/debug etec. That way you learn to code in Java and if you ever move to a different IDE you don't need to relearn the IDE.

Comment: For an alternative approach you can add a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel`. You should be able to do this in any IDE. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540661/tablemodellistener-and-multiple-column-validation/3541876#3541876 for a working example of this approach. However, this solution isn't as good as the first suggestion because now the "business logic" of your TableModel is in two different places.