# How do I make my JTable cell listen for value changes?

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JTable` with 3 columns, namely: `firstvalue`, `secvalue` and `total`. My table is editable, so at runtime my `firstvalue` and `secvalue` columns are initialized with value 0.0. Now the user has to type in a value in any of the 2 column cells and then `total` column in that same row has to display the sum of those 2 numbers without any button being clicked.
I tried using `TableCellLister` but it's giving errors on all lines with the key *TableCellListener*.
This is my code:

```java
Action myaction = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        TablecellListener tblisten = (TableCellListener)e.getSource();
        int row = tblisten.getRow();
        int col = tblisten.getColumn();
        Integer secondcol = 1;
        Integer totalcol = 2;
        int sum;
        //get value
        Integer fval = (Integer)table.getModel().getValueAt(row, col);
        Integer sval = (Integer)table.getModel().getValueAt(row, scol);

        //find the sum

        //set value
        table.setvalueAt(sum,row,totalcol);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code shows an ActionListener, which cannot be passed as a TableModelListener (which you probably should use) or as a CellEditorListener (which you probably should not use).  As far as I know, there is no Swing class called TableCellListener.

Comment: *it's giving errors on all lines with the key TableCellListener.* - which is not a standard JDK class. You need to download the class from [Table Cell Listener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/). However, in this case, you don't really need to use this class since the type of processing you are doing can be handled by the `TableModelListener` as demonstrated in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541876/131872

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a `TableModel`. As stated in [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), it is usually appropriate to extend [AbstractTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html), for instance:

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    static class RowModel {
        double firstValue;
        double secondValue;

        public RowModel(double firstValue, double secondValue) {
            this.firstValue = firstValue;
            this.secondValue = secondValue;
        }
    };

    private final List<RowModel> rows = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addRow(double firstValue, double secondValue) {
        int pos = rows.size();
        rows.add(new RowModel(firstValue, secondValue));
        fireTableRowsInserted(pos, pos);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return rows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
                return Double.class;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return "First value";
            case 1:
                return "Second value";
            case 2:
                return "Total";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < rows.size()) {
            RowModel row = rows.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return row.firstValue;
                case 1:
                    return row.secondValue;
                case 2:
                    return row.firstValue + row.secondValue;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < rows.size()
                && columnIndex >= 0 && columnIndex <= 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < rows.size()) {
            RowModel row = rows.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    row.firstValue = toDouble(aValue);
                    fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                    fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, 2);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    row.secondValue = toDouble(aValue);
                    fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                    fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, 2);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private double toDouble(Object aValue) {
        if (aValue instanceof Number) {
            return ((Number)aValue).doubleValue();
        } else if (aValue instanceof String) {
            try {
                return Double.parseDouble((String)aValue);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // return 0;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The `JTable` displays the values in the `TableModel` by calling the model's `getValueAt` method. As you can see, in the above code, that method receives the indexes of a cell in the table and, for the `total` column, it returns the sum of the other two columns.

You then create an instance of the model and attach it to the `JTable`:

```
MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
table.setModel(model);
model.addRow(0,0);
model.addRow(0,0);
model.addRow(0,0);
```

UPDATE:

Turns out that the part of `getValueAt` dealing with `rowIndex < 0` is useless.

Comment: @Abra in `getValueAt` and in `setValueAt` where changes are notified for both the cell being modified (by the editor) and the "Total" cell.