# Update JTable upon a change in the data model

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JDialog that updates user data, and once I click the update button, it validates the data, makes a PUT request to an endpoint created by me, and updates the user data in the database. So far, everything is fine

```
    private void btnActualizarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        URL url;
        if (validaDatos()) {
            try {

                Object idUsuario = recuperaPersona.get("id");
                url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/usuario/" + idUsuario);

                //Preparar la información a enviar
                Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                params.put("nombre", txtNombre.getText());
                params.put("primerApellido", txtPrimerApellido.getText());
                params.put("segundoApellido", txtSegundoApellido.getText());
                params.put("calle", txtCalle.getText());
                params.put("ciudad", txtCiudad.getText());
                params.put("codigoPostal", txtCodigoPostal.getText());
                params.put("fechaAlta", sdf.format(dchFechaAlta.getDate()));
                params.put("fechaNacimiento", sdf.format(dchFechaNacimiento.getDate()));
                if (ValidadorFormulario.validarDNI(txtDni.getText())) {
                    params.put("dni", txtDni.getText());
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El DNI no es correcto");
                }
                params.put("correoElectronico", txtCorreoElectronico.getText());
                params.put("telefono", txtTelefono.getText());
                params.put("fotoUsuario", rutaDeLaFoto);

                String jsonData = gson.toJson(params);
                System.out.println(jsonData);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                try (OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
                    byte[] input = jsonData.getBytes("utf-8");
                    os.write(input, 0, input.length);
                }
                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == 200) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paciente actualizado correctamente");
                    
                    
                    consumoApiVerPacientes.fireTableDataChanged();
                    
                    dispose();
                    
                }
                
                
                
                

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Once this is done, I update the data model with the fireTableDataChanged() method in order to update the table in the parent Frame of this JDialog. The problem is that the data model does not update in this way, leaving the table unchanged and not updated.

This is my data model:

```
public class ConsumoApiVerPacientes extends AbstractTableModel{
    private StringBuilder informationString;
    private JSONArray jSONArray;
    JSONObject objetoJson;

    private final String[] nombresColumnas = {"Nombre", "Primer Apellido", "Segundo Apellido", "DNI","Fecha de Nacimiento"};

    public ConsumoApiVerPacientes() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/usuarios/todos");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.connect();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Ocurrió un error: " + responseCode);
            } else {
                informationString = new StringBuilder();
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());

                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    informationString.append(scanner.nextLine());
                }
                scanner.close();

                jSONArray = new JSONArray(informationString.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return jSONArray.length();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int fila, int columna) {
         objetoJson = jSONArray.getJSONObject(fila);
        switch (columna) {
            case 0:
                return objetoJson.get("nombre");
            case 1:
                return objetoJson.get("primerApellido");
            case 2:
                return objetoJson.get("segundoApellido");
            case 3:
                return objetoJson.get("dni");
            case 4:
                return objetoJson.get("fechaNacimiento");
           
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int i) {
        return nombresColumnas[i];
    }
    
    public JSONObject recuperaPersona(int indiceTabla){
        return jSONArray.getJSONObject(indiceTabla);
        
        
    }
    
  
}
```

The problem, I believe, is that the fireTableDataChanged() doesn't propagate from the JDialog to the parent element. Therefore, I would appreciate assistance in this regard

Here is the frame where the table is:

```
public class VerPacienteParaActualizar extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public ConsumoApiVerPacientes consumoApiVerPacientes; 
    

    VerPacienteCompletoParaActualizar verPacienteCompletoParaActualizar;

    public VerPacienteParaActualizar() {
        initComponents();
        tblVerPacientes.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 12));
        tblVerPacientes.getTableHeader().setOpaque(false);
        tblVerPacientes.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(0, 152, 152));
        consumoApiVerPacientes = new ConsumoApiVerPacientes();
        tblVerPacientes.setModel(consumoApiVerPacientes);
        

        traeListaTodosLosPacientes();
        
        
    }

    public void traeListaTodosLosPacientes() {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/usuarios/todos");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.connect();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Ocurró un error: " + responseCode);
            } else {
                StringBuilder informationString = new StringBuilder();
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());

                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    informationString.append(scanner.nextLine());
                }
                scanner.close();

                JSONArray jSONArray = new JSONArray(informationString.toString());

            }
        } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public JTable traeTabla(){
        return tblVerPacientes;
    }

private void btnBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        switch ((String) cmbParametro.getSelectedItem()) {
            case "Primer Apellido":
                ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorPrimerApellido consumoApiVerPacientesPorPrimerApellido = new ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorPrimerApellido(txtCriterio.getText());
                tblVerPacientes.setModel(consumoApiVerPacientesPorPrimerApellido);
                buscaPacientePorPrimerApellido(txtCriterio.getText());
                consumoApiVerPacientesPorPrimerApellido.fireTableDataChanged();
                break;
            case "Nombre":
                ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorNombre consumoApiVerPacientesPorNombre = new ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorNombre((txtCriterio.getText()));
                tblVerPacientes.setModel(consumoApiVerPacientesPorNombre);
                buscaPacientePorNombre(txtCriterio.getText());
                consumoApiVerPacientesPorNombre.fireTableDataChanged();
                break;
            case "Segundo Apellido":
                ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorSegundoApellido consumoApiVerPacientesPorSegundoApellido = new ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorSegundoApellido(txtCriterio.getText());
                tblVerPacientes.setModel(consumoApiVerPacientesPorSegundoApellido);
                buscaPacientePorSegundoApellido(txtCriterio.getText());
                consumoApiVerPacientesPorSegundoApellido.fireTableDataChanged();
                break;
            case "Todos":
                tblVerPacientes.setModel(consumoApiVerPacientes);
                consumoApiVerPacientes.fireTableDataChanged();

                break;

            case "DNI":
                ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorDni consumoApiVerPacientesPorDni = new ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorDni(txtCriterio.getText());
                tblVerPacientes.setModel(consumoApiVerPacientesPorDni);
                buscaPacientePorDni(txtCriterio.getText());
                consumoApiVerPacientesPorDni.fireTableDataChanged();
                break;

        }


    }                                         
 
    private void tblVerPacientesMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             

        Point puntoClickeado = evt.getPoint();
        int filaDelPuntoClickeado = tblVerPacientes.rowAtPoint(puntoClickeado);
        int filaSeleccionada = tblVerPacientes.getSelectedRow();
        switch ((String) cmbParametro.getSelectedItem()) {
            case "Todos":
                verPacienteCompletoParaActualizar = new VerPacienteCompletoParaActualizar(this, true,consumoApiVerPacientes, filaDelPuntoClickeado);
                System.out.println("2-"+consumoApiVerPacientes.hashCode());
                verPacienteCompletoParaActualizar.setVisible(true);

                break;
            case "Segundo Apellido":
                ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorSegundoApellido consumoApiVerPacientesPorSegundoApellido = new ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorSegundoApellido(txtCriterio.getText());
                verPacienteCompletoParaActualizar = new VerPacienteCompletoParaActualizar(this, true, consumoApiVerPacientesPorSegundoApellido, filaDelPuntoClickeado);
                verPacienteCompletoParaActualizar.setVisible(true);
                break;
            case "Nombre":
                ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorNombre consumoApiVerPacientesPorNombre = new ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorNombre(txtCriterio.getText());
                verPacienteCompletoParaActualizar = new VerPacienteCompletoParaActualizar(this, true, consumoApiVerPacientesPorNombre, filaDelPuntoClickeado);
                verPacienteCompletoParaActualizar.setVisible(true);
                break;
            case "Primer Apellido":
                ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorPrimerApellido consumoApiVerPacientesPorPrimerApellido = new ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorPrimerApellido(txtCriterio.getText());
                verPacienteCompletoParaActualizar = new VerPacienteCompletoParaActualizar(this, true, consumoApiVerPacientesPorPrimerApellido, filaDelPuntoClickeado);
                verPacienteCompletoParaActualizar.setVisible(true);
                break;
            case "DNI":
                ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorDni consumoApiVerPacientesPorDni = new ConsumoApiVerPacientesPorDni(txtCriterio.getText());
                verPacienteCompletoParaActualizar = new VerPacienteCompletoParaActualizar(this, true, consumoApiVerPacientesPorDni, filaDelPuntoClickeado);
                verPacienteCompletoParaActualizar.setVisible(true);
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: We would also appreciate assistance.  Edit your question to include a [mre] that we can compile and test in our IDE that removes the database code, replaces it with simulated data, and focuses on just updating a `JTable`.  Like [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) does here.

Comment: I ´ve already edit my question

Comment: *I update the data model with the fireTableDataChanged() method* - incorrect. Changes should be made to the model and then it is the responsibility of the Model to invoke that method, not your application. However, in your case it looks like you are replacing the entire model by using the `setModel(...)` method on the table so that will update the table. The code you posted is NOT an [mre] so we can't offer any further advice. Here is an example of an MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541876/131872